# Solutions of equations in a subfield $F_1\subset F$ (why is this true?)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

I'm reading the book *Linear Algebra* by Hoffman and Kunze and on page 15 of the 2nd edition, they made an assertion which intrigues me.

> Let us observe one final thing about the system $AX = Y$. Suppose the entries of the matrix $A$ and the scalars $y_1,\dots,y_m$ happen to lie in a subfield $F_1$ of the field $F$. If the system of equations $AX = Y$ has a solution with $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in $F$, it has a solution with $x_1,\dots,x_n$ in $F_1$. For, over either field, the condition for the system to have a solution is that certain relations hold between $y_1,\dots,y_m$ in $F_1$ (the relations $z_i = 0$ for $i > r$, above). For example, if $AX =Y$ is a system of linear equations in which the scalars $y_k$ and $A_{ij}$ are real numbers, and if there is a solution in which $x_1,\dots,x_n$ are complex numbers, then there is a solution with $x_1,\dots,x_n$ real numbers.

The converse is obviously true. However, the claim made by the authors seems very mysterious to me (see for instance: $x^2+1=0$ has solutions in $\mathbb C$, but not in $\mathbb R$). Can anyone throw light on this?

Comment: But $x^2+1$ is not linear.

Comment: One way to see that this is the case is to note that the process of Gaussian elimination stays the same for a given matrix even if you expand the field of scalars.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the system of linear equations $AX = Y$, we perform a sequence of elementary row operations on the augmented matrix $A' = [A_1\ \cdots\ A_n \ Y]$ to obtain the system $RX = Z$, which is equivalent to the original system.

If $R$ has exactly $r$ non-zero rows ($1 \leq r \leq m$), then in the system $RX = Z$ the latter $m-r$ equations are
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= z_{r+1}\\
\vdots &\quad\  \vdots \\
0 &= z_m.
\end{align}
$$
The authors have shown that a solution to $AX = Y$ exists if and only if a solution to $RX = Z$ exists if and only if $z_i = 0$ for all $i > r$.

Now, suppose that when we view the system $AX = Y$ over the field $F \supset F_1$ it has a solution, that is, with $x_1,\dots,x_n \in F$. Then, the conditions $z_i = 0$ for all $i > r$ are satisfied, where each $z_i$ is a linear combination of $y_1,\dots,y_m$ with coefficients in $F$. But, since the entries of $A$ and $Y$ lie in the subfield $F_1$ of $F$, each $z_i$ is a linear combination of $y_1,\dots,y_m$ with coefficients in $F_1$. This does not change the fact that each $z_i = 0$, so the condition for a solution of $AX = Y$ to exist over the field $F_1$ is automatically satisfied, namely that $z_i = 0$ for all $i > r$. Hence, if a solution exists over $F$, it also exists over $F_1$.

---

Regarding your example, it is true that $x^2 + 1 = 0$ has a solution over $\mathbb{C}$ but not over $\mathbb{R}$, but this is not a contradiction of the above conclusion because $x^2 + 1$ is not linear. So, such a relation can never arise among the entries $y_1,\dots,y_m$ in the above problem.

This shows that the assertion that you pointed out is indeed non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

If possible let $AX=Y$ has a solution in $F$, but it has no solution in $F_1$. So, for some $i \in \{r+1,...,n\}$, $z_i \neq 0$. (Here we are considering the given system of the linear equations over the field $F_1$). As $F_1 \subset F$, so $z_i \neq 0$ also for the said $i$, when we consider the given system of the linear equations over the field $F$. So, $AX=Y$ has no solution in $F$, which is a contradiction.
So, if $AX=Y$ has a solution in $F$,it has also a solution in the subfield $F_1$ of the field $F$.